# How can I fix undefined variable problem?

Tags: php, laravel, voyager

My `$links` and `$sliderimages` variables work great. The `$klas` variable has been made by the same way like the first two I said, and for some reason it says that it is undefined variable.

First `$klas` was meant for another view, however I decided to test it out on my home page view where the other 2 variables were working were, but when i have put the `$klas` the same error occurs.

```
Route::get('/', function () {
        $sliderimages = App\Sliderimage::all();
        $links = App\Link::all();
        $klas = App\Kla::all();
        return view('home', compact('sliderimages'), compact('links'), compact('klas'));
    });
```

That is on web.php file

```
 @foreach($links as $link)
        <div class="col-lg-4">
                <img src="{{ Voyager::image( $link->image ) }}"  class="rounded-circle"  width="140" height="140" style="margin-left:25%">
          <h2>"{{$link->title}}"</h2>
          <p>"{{$link->text}}"</p>
          <p><a class="btn btn-secondary" href="{{$link->slug}}" role="button">За повече информация. &raquo;</a></p>
        </div>
        @endforeach
      </div>     

      @foreach($klas as $kla)
        <p>"{{$kla->klastitle}}"</p>
        @endforeach
```

That is on home.blade . php

The error is:

> Undefined variable: klas (View:  D:\xampp\htdocs\koko\diplomnata\resources\views\home.blade.php)

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Notice: Undefined variable", "Notice: Undefined index", and "Notice: Undefined offset" using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/notice-undefined-variable-notice-undefined-index-and-notice-undefined)

Comment: Please edit your question and paste the relevant code in - don't use an image.

Comment: You have not shown the code of `HomeController` though.

Comment: The HomeController is not needed. I am calling the variables from web.php

Comment: The problem is not the / believe me.

Comment: Use logics inside of controller instead of route. Thats a genuine way...

Answer (score 1):

Change this:

```
return view('home', compact('sliderimages'), compact('links'), compact('klas'));
```

To this:

```
return view('home', compact('sliderimages', 'links', 'klas'));
```

Or for more longer but IMO more readable syntax:

```
return view('home')
    ->with('sliderimages', $sliderImages)
    ->with('links', $links)
    ->with('klas', $klas);
```

https://laravel.com/docs/master/views#passing-data-to-views

Comment: If you say so. The four-arguments `view()` call you show in your question is, to my knowledge, invalid and won't work.

Comment: The thing is it work with sliderimages and links, but not klas. Klas for ment for another view anyways I was just trying to test it on Home view, because I thought It may work like it did with the first 2

Comment: Have you tried both the compact() and the longer syntax?

Comment: Yes I have. That is definetly not the problem.